# Show that if $\models \varphi \supset \psi$, then there is an interpolant for $\varphi$ and $\psi$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Full question:

> Show that if $\models\varphi \supset \psi$, and $\varphi$ is not a contradiction nor $\psi$ a tautology, then there is an interpolant for $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem. In my professor's notes he gave us a hint, but I'm still not seeing why we are choosing the interpolant to be $\varphi(\top,q) \vee \varphi(\bot,q)$, or why we defined $\top=q\supset q$, and similarly $\bot=\sim(q\supset q)$.

Can anyone highlight why we chose that as our interpolant?

Below is my professor's hint:

[image: Professor's Hint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: The definitions of $\perp$ and $\top$ is just so that $\perp$ is a sentence which is always false, $\top$ is a sentence which is always true, and they each only use symbols in both $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

So: What does this mean for the interpolant "$\varphi(\top, q)\vee\varphi(\perp, q)$"? (Call that formula "$\hat\varphi$" for simplicity.) Well, $\top$ and $\perp$ - "true" and "false" - are the two possible values of the variable $p$, which is the "illicit" variable - the one $\varphi$ uses but $\psi$ doesn't, which we need to get rid of. For instance, if $\varphi$ were the sentence "$p\vee q$," then $\hat{\varphi}$ would be equivalent to the sentence "Either $p$ is true and (True or $q$), or $p$ is false and (False or $q$)." Importantly: any truth assignment $\nu$ making $\varphi$ true will make $\hat{\varphi}$ true - if $\nu$ makes $p$ true, then $\nu$ will make $\varphi(\top, q)$ true, and if $\nu$ makes $p$ false, then $\nu$ will make $\varphi(\perp, q)$ true.  So $\hat{\varphi}$ is a consequence of $\varphi$ gotten by basically breaking $\varphi$ into all the possible cases for $p$.$^{footnote}$

Conversely, it is **not** the case that $\hat{\varphi}$ implies $\varphi$ - this is a good exercise - but the following is true:

> $(*)\quad$ If there's a truth assignment $\nu$ making $\hat{\varphi}$ true, then there's a truth assignment $\nu'$ making both $\varphi$ and $\hat{\varphi}$ true, which has the same value on $q$ as $\nu$ does.

Just look at which clause of $\varphi$ winds up being true under $\nu$, and to define $\nu'$ set $p$ to $\top$ or $\perp$ accordingly.

This property $(*)$ is in fact where the relationship between $\hat{\varphi}$ and $\psi$, the other half of our desired result, comes from: suppose $\varphi\implies\psi$ is a tautology. We want to show $\hat{\varphi}\implies\psi$ is a tautology. So let $\nu$ be any truth assignment to $p$ and $q$ which makes $\hat{\varphi}$ true. Then we can find a truth assignment $\nu'$, which agrees with $\nu$ about $q$, making $\varphi$ true. That means this assignment can be extended to one making $\psi$ true.

Does this help?

---

$^{footnote}$  If $\varphi$ had **two** illicit variables, $p_1$ and $p_2$, then $\hat{\varphi}$ would have four clauses. Etc.

Comment: Thanks for the write up. I'll continue to try to prove the result on my own, but your explanation helped a great deal. I'll reply with a comment if I find anything else confusing.

Comment: @B.V. Glad to help!

Comment: How would one go about demonstrating the (*) proposition? I'm getting a feel for what's going on here with this exercise, and it seems like proving the converse relies heavily on that proposition. It also seems that it's implied in my professor's hint. Also, would it be an application of local determination to the formulas $v(\varphi\prime)$ and $v(\varphi)$? Or am I mistaken?